# Replace multiple variables in a django url tag using js variables

Tags: javascript, python, django

At this moment the way I am doing it is relatively ugly and it is as follow:

```
view.py
def some_plot(request, day, team, month, person):
    data = {
        "day": day,
        "team": team,
        "month": month,
        "person": person
    }
    return render(request, 'some_plot.html', data)
```

and `some_plot.html` looks like this:

```
let mapObj = {
    day : "{{ day }}",
    team : "{{ team }}",
    month : "{{ month }}",
    person : "{{ person }}"
}

d3.json("{% url "my_view_url" day team month person %}".replace(/day|team|month|person/gi, function(matched){
return mapObj[matched];
}), function(data){ # plot stuff
```

Is there a more efficient way to end up with the same result, as this is slightly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

For instance I have an app with name task so to go the index of task I do http://localhost:8000/task the url has as name index

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = 'task'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add_task/', views.add_task, name='add_task'),
    path('add_subtask/<int:task_id>/', views.add_subtask, name='add_subtask'),
]
```

So in my template I can do something like that to go to call the second url

```
var add_task_url = "{% url 'task:index' %}add_task/"
```

And to go to the next url

```
var add_subtask_url = "{% url 'task:index' %}add_subtask/" + '1/' //you can replace '1/' by '{{day}}/' and add others one
```